# Cell repopulating over each other in TableView

Tags: swift, tableview, cell

I'm currently working with a tableview that contains three sections. Each section loads it's data from an array that is loaded from a backend and is stored in a local array. The data downloads and displays without issue, but once I scroll, the cells reload themselves over their previous data. The reason I caught it, outside of the memory warning, was that the cell contains an image with a drop shadow and the shadow grows darker with each scroll. I have a feeling the issue is related to how I'm calling the cell at indexPath for each section but can't seem to find a solution. I've searched around and haven't been able to find a resolution yet.

The cells all share the same custom class and reload their respective data through the same outlets.
Not sure if this is relevant to the issue but the view is called from information in the AppDelegate.
Here's the code that I'm working with staring with number of rows in section.

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

```
    if section == 0 {

        return likesName.count

    } else if section == 1 {

        return commentsName.count

    } else if section == 2 {

        return bookmarksName.count

}

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    if indexPath.section == 0 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("toggleCell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as! RightToggleCell

    cell.userAvatar.layer.cornerRadius = cell.userAvatar.frame.size.width/2
    cell.userAvatar.clipsToBounds = true

    cell.artworkImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
    cell.artworkImage.clipsToBounds = true

    cell.artistName.text = likesName[indexPath.row]

    cell.information.text = "liked your artwork"

            likesImage[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in

                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

                    cell.artworkImage.image = downloadedImage

                }
            }

            likesAvatar[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in

                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

                    cell.userAvatar.image = downloadedImage

                }
            }


    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("toggleCell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as! RightToggleCell

        cell.userAvatar.layer.cornerRadius = cell.userAvatar.frame.size.width/2
        cell.userAvatar.clipsToBounds = true

        cell.artworkImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
        cell.artworkImage.clipsToBounds = true

        cell.artistName.text = commentsName[indexPath.row]

        cell.information.text = commentsInformation[indexPath.row]

            commentsImage[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in

                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

                    cell.artworkImage.image = downloadedImage

                }
            }

            commentsAvatar[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in

                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

                    cell.userAvatar.image = downloadedImage

                }
            }


    } else if indexPath.section == 2 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("toggleCell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as! RightToggleCell

        cell.userAvatar.layer.cornerRadius = cell.userAvatar.frame.size.width/2
        cell.userAvatar.clipsToBounds = true

        cell.artworkImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
        cell.artworkImage.clipsToBounds = true

        cell.artistName.text = bookmarksName[indexPath.row]

         cell.information.text = "bookmarked your artwork"

            bookmarksImage[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in

                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

                    cell.artworkImage.image = downloadedImage

                }
            }

            bookmarksAvatar[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in

                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

                    cell.userAvatar.image = downloadedImage

                }
            }
        }


    return cell

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to line up your code, but it looks like you have:

```
let cell = ...
if ... {
    let cell = ...
} else if ... {
    let cell = ...
}
return cell
```

If this is what you have, the `let cell` inside each `if` is only scoped to exist within that `if`. Therefore, the `return cell` at the end will return the initial, empty cell. If this is the case, you should change it to:

```
if ... {
    let cell = ...
    return cell
} else if ... {
    let cell = ...
    return cell
} else {
    let cell = ...
    return cell
}
```

Note that the last condition must just be `else` and not `else if` or the compiler will tell you not all code paths return a value (when the last "if" fails). However, you're saying it's basically working, so something doesn't make sense.

Either way, cells get reused for new rows once a row moves off screen. Therefore, by the time your `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` returns, the cell might belong to a different row. Given the drop-shadow is getting darker, it sounds like you have code in `RightToggleCell` that is rerunning when a cell gets reused.

When you load data in the background, you should store it outside the cell, and reload that row when the load finishes. Something (very roughly) along the lines of:

```
likesImage[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in
    if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
        artworkImages[indexPath.row] = downloadedImage
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath.row], withRowAnimation: true)
        })
    }
}
```

The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should display the relevant artworkImages if it's available, or use the above code if not. Note that any updating of the UI must be done on the main thread, which is why `dispatch_async` is being called above.

Comment: I'm equally confused. I haven't run into this issue with any other table that I've populated. RightToggleCell doesn't contain anything outside of IBOutlets. I switched the cellForIndexRow to return each cell inside the if let statements but the function is still expecting a return function at the end

Comment: Is there a better way to specify with section receives it's data? The cells in each section receive everything correctly but I'm not sure if the way that I constructed it is causing an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing everything on the TableViewController i suggest you to put this code into your "RightToggleCell".

```
override func awakeFromNib() {

self.userAvatar.layer.cornerRadius =  self.userAvatar.frame.size.width/2
self.userAvatar.clipsToBounds = true

self.artworkImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
self.artworkImage.clipsToBounds = true

}
```

By doing this iOS doesn't modify cornerRadius and clipsToBounds everytime you reload your TableView

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I have everything else in my project set up that way, not sure how I missed that. I'm experiencing the same issue though. The drop shadow that I'm referring to is actually an image. That image and everything else in the cell is reloaded each time I scroll up and down the table.

Answer (score 0):

With the guidance from Michael, I moved return cell inside of each if let statement and returned UITableViewCell() outside of the statements and that resolved the issue. Thanks again Michael, I up voted your response but I don't have a high enough reputation for it to post.